# Editing users in ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity, razor-pages

I'm just trying to make an Edit page for my Identity database. I'm using Razor Pages, and I'm new to it. I found some solutions for MVC, but they don't really work for me because of using Views and other stuff like Controllers. I have a main page Index.cshtml, where I can choose the users from a list like the image below

[image: list]

And delete them by clicking a submit button.

I handeled deletion like this:

CSHTML file:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" asp-route-id="@user.Id" asp-page-handler="Del">Del</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" asp-route-id="@user.Id" asp-page-handler="Change">Change</button>
```

CSHTML.CS file:

```
   public ApplicationUser ApUser { get; set; }
   public async Task<ActionResult> OnPostDel(string id)
    {
        ApUsers = _userManager.Users.ToList();
        ApUser = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
        if (ApUser != null)
        {
            IdentityResult result = await _userManager.DeleteAsync(ApUser);
        }
        //return RedirectToAction("UserChange/Index");
        return RedirectToPage("Index");
    }
```

And it works just fine by me, but I need to Edit too. So my Edit POST method in Index.cshtml.cs looks like:

```
   public async Task<ActionResult> OnPostChange(string id)
   {
        ApUsers = _userManager.Users.ToList();
        ApUser = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
        if (ApUser == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else return RedirectToPage("Edit");
   }
```

And my Edit.cshtml.cs look like this:

```
<form asp-action="Edit" asp-controller="Users">
<div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Email" class="control-label">Email</label>
    <input type="text" asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Score" class="control-label">Score</label>
    <input type="number" asp-for="Score" class="form-control" />
</div>
...
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" asp-page-handler="Edit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
</div>
</form>
```

And Edit.cshtml.cs:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostEdit(string id)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ApUser = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
        if (ApUser != null)
        {
            ApUser.Email = Email;
            ApUser.UserName = Email;
            ApUser.Score = Score;
            ApUser.Position = Position;
            ApUser.Sequence = Sequence;

            var result = await _userManager.UpdateAsync(ApUser);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

And it doesn't work of course. I'm just trying to remake some MVC example to Razor Pages. Maybe you have better solutions for this, but I really stuck here.

Comment: **And it doesn't work of course** What that means? Error message? What browser debug console said?

Comment: "It doesn't work of course" is not a very good problem description. I cannot see a clear question here. What is the problem you have with the code? What is it doing that differs from what you expect? Are there error messages? Which error messages?

Comment: I'm sorry, the real question is "How to make it work?", because I don't know how to send ID parameter from Index.cshtml.cs  OnPostChange method, which should open Edit.cshtml page, to Edit.cshtml.cs methods like OnPostEdit

Comment: Try adding `asp-page="Edit"` to your edit button?  See [ASP.NET Core Demystified - Razor Pages](https://exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-core-demystified-razor-pages/) for details.

Comment: You need a **GET** route for your `Edit` page. You are redirecting there so the browser will hit it with a GET request. There, you need to display a form that then submits via POST, where you update the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, yeah, I just made a button on my Index.cshtml page like this, it provides asp-route-id to Edit page:

```
<a asp-page="Edit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" asp-route-id="@user.Id">Edit</a>
```

Made an InputModel on Edit.cshtml.cs file:

```
   public InputModel Input { get; set; }
    public class InputModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="{0} не может быть пустым")]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage ="Неверный формат {0}")]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите {0}")]
        [StringLength(5, ErrorMessage = "{0} должна быть из {1} символов", MinimumLength = 5)]
        [Display(Name = "Последовательность")]
        public string Sequence { get; set; }
        ...
    }
```

Just added in Edit.cshtml file @page "{id}", to provide it through previous page
OnPost method provides User changes from the model:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string id)
{
    ApUser = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Page();
    }
    ApUser.Email = Input.Email;
    ApUser.Score = Input.Score;
    ApUser.Sequence = Input.Sequence;
    ApUser.Position = 0;
    await _userManager.UpdateAsync(ApUser);
    Message = ApUser.Email;
    return RedirectToPage("Index");
}
```

And the I just use a model in Edit.cshtml

```
<form method="post" asp-route-id="@Model.ApUser.Id">
<div class="form-group">
<label asp-for="Input.Email"></label>
<input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" value="@Model.ApUser.Email.ToString()" />
<span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
...
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
</form>
```